# How to merge into array?

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, mongoose

Here is my array from db,

```
[
    {
      "_id": "58144e6c0c8d7534f4307269",
      "doctor_id": "5813221ace684e2b3f5f0a6d",
      "prescription": [
        {
          "_id": "58144e6c0c8d7534f430726a",
          "medicine_id": "10011241343"
        }
]
```

I want to merge with only prescription like this

```
[
    {
      "_id": "58144e6c0c8d7534f4307269",
      "doctor_id": "5813221ace684e2b3f5f0a6d",
      "prescription": [
        {
          "_id": "58144e6c0c8d7534f430726a",
          "medicine_id": "10011241343"
        },
      "prescription": [
        {
          "_id": "58144e6c0c8d7534f430726a", // it should be autogenerated
          "medicine_id": "10011241344"
        }
]
```

How can I do this?

I have tried like this

```
var arr = data.presription
arr=req.body// which contains only medicine id
```

and then by

```
dbModel.user.findById(data._id, function(err, data) {    
    data.prescription = arr;
    data.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(202).json({
                "success": "0",
            });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                "success": "1"
            });
        }
    })
});
```

But it is saving the same. How can I do this?

Note: Even when I do `console.log(arr)` only the old data is printing.

Comment: Have you tried using a jQuery merge? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/

Comment: @JordiKroon Sorry i can't use `$` inside node

Comment: If you can't use $, you can still use the alternative "jQuery" syntax.

Answer (score 0):

So data.presription is an array from the start.

```
data.presription.push( {
    "_id": "58144e6c0c8d7534f430726a",
    "medicine_id": "10011241344"
});
```

This is NOT a merge, what you want to do is to append (or push) items into an existing array.